# Bash Script: Adding newline after `read` command with -s flag

Tags: bash, git, shell, echo

I am working on a BASH script that will install & configure `git` on a (new) linux machine and also clone the user's chosen repository. The script takes a couple of arguments and I'm trying to use the `read` command to handle that, like so:

```
read -s -p "Please enter a valid Personal Access Token(PAT): " pat
read -p "Please enter your Github username: " username
```

On the first line, I added the `-s` flag to silence the user's input so that it does not display on the terminal. However, when I hit `enter` after inputting, the next command just runs on the same same line.

1. My first attempt was to try to add a new line character to the first line and then to the second line:

`read -s -p "Please enter PAT: \n" pat`

`read -p $"\nPlease enter username: " username`. Both just printed the `\n` on the terminal.

2. Then I tried with the `$` expansion character on both lines:

`read -s -p $"Please enter PAT: \n" pat`; and

`read -p "Please enter PAT: "$"\n" -s pat`

`read -s -p $"\nPlease enter username: " username`. These also just printed the `\n` character.

Out of desperation, I even tried to lend the `-e` flag from `echo`; which didn't work, obviously.

I expected that the lines just print one after the other on separate lines. I know this might seem like a small issue, but I can imagine how confusing it can be for a user that is not too familiar with the shell.

Comment: Try `read -s -p $'\nPlease enter username: ' username` instead. The point is the single quotes.

Comment: `-p` does not interpret \n as a line feed. You can do it like tshiono suggested in his comment, or you just put an `echo` between the two `read`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page of the command, use this option :

> -r
> Do not treat a Backslash as an escape character.  The
> backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a
> backslash-newline pair can not be used as a line continuation. Without
> this option, any backslashes in the input will be discarded. You
> should almost always use the -r option with read.